# Method applicable for any object

Tags: java, arrays, methods, overriding

I created a method that turns any two dimensional array clockwise.

```
public boolean[][] rotateClockWise(boolean[][] array)   {
    if (array.length != array[0].length) return null;
    boolean[][] turned = new boolean[array.length][array.length];
    for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++)
        for (int a = 0; a < array.length; a++)
            turned[i][a] = array[array.length - a - 1][i];
    return turned;
}
```

This method currently only applies to boolean arrays. Is it possible to modify this one method to apply to any object array?

(P.S. I tried changing the word "boolean" to "Object" in the code, but then the program failed to compile because there was "no suitable method found")

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Could you provide the entire compilation error when you replaced the word boolean with Object in your code sample?

Comment: Primitive arrays cannot be assigned to object array variables. Look at all the duplicate methods in the `java.util.Arrays` class.

Answer (score 0):

You got "no suitable method found" error because there was a parameter type mismatch. You can resolve it by supplying an Object parameter like below.
However, the return type will be `Object[][]` with this new method and you have to change the type of assigned variables to `Object[][]` wherever you called this method. It might even require some further modifications in your code.

```
public Object[][] rotateClockWise(Object twoDArray)   {
    Object[][] array = (Object[][]) twoDArray;
    if (array.length != array[0].length) return null;
    Object[][] turned = new Object[array.length][array.length];
    for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++)
        for (int a = 0; a < array.length; a++)
            turned[i][a] = array[array.length - a - 1][i];
    return turned;
}
```

Comment: You've worsened the problem. What has been a compilation error is now a runtime exception (ClassCastException). `2dArray` is not a valid identifier btw.